# How to Set an EditText uneditable/disabled

Tags: android

I have a editView with OnClick event to show Calender like this :

```
 <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/checkOut"
            android:onClick="onPlayButton"
            android:inputType="date"
            />
```

I want to disable typing in this EditView in order user just could select date from my calender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `android:focusable="false"` in your `EditText` tag

Comment: this does not disable writing in `EditText`.

Comment: this works for me. thanks.

Comment: @vrundpurohit It works for me. :)
The soft keyboard does not pop up when it does not receive focus.

Comment: @samirariazati you can accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: @samirariazati but you still seeing that courser .. aren't you?

Comment: @vrundpurohit  I dont see the courser anymore.

Comment: well that's great if it worked for you... but i still recommend to use `android:editable="false"` instead of `android:focusable="false"`.

Answer (score 0):

To disable an edit view progrmatically use

```
editView.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

> By Java

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

> By xml

```
android:editable="false"
```

or  if you want to show the edittext but not input any values

```
edittext.setInputType(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use some thing like this

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:editable="false"
    android:inputType="none" />
```